# Escape curly braces as value in a textfield from ExtJS

Tags: extjs, escaping, textfield, curly-braces

How can i escape curly braces in ExtJs to print it into a textfield?

```
bind: {
    fieldLabel: '{fieldLabel}',
    value: '\{id\}{defaultValue}'
}
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can always type html code instead of braces:

`value: '&#123;id&#125;{defaultValue}'`.

I hope is better solution possible.

Comment: I thought so, too. But this leads to an empty input field. It seems like it will be interpreted as well as {id}.

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve. Can you attach the image of expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Usually escape character is forward slash  "/"
Try using below code

```
bind: {
    fieldLabel: '{fieldLabel}',
    value: '/{id/}{defaultValue}'
}
```